# How to use purrr to replace a modifying for loop in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Group = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'),
  Value = c(12, 88, 54, 76, 23, 44, 60, 52, 18)
)
```

I want to scale each group to a median of 100 and replace the `Value` column with the new value so the dataframe looks like this:

```
df_desired <- data.frame(
  Group = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'),
  Value = c(20, 169.23, 122.73, 126.67, 44.23, 100, 100, 100, 40.91)
)
```

Using a scale_helper like this:

```
scale_helper <- function(x, value) x * value / median(x)
```

I could do this with a `for` loop, but I want to use `purrr` instead, if possible. Is there a straightforward way to do it using `purrr`, or is a `for` loop the better way to go here?

Comment: You don't explain why you want to do this with `purrr`.

Comment: Do I need to explain that? I’d like an alternative to a for loop.

Comment: Are you looking for `df %>% group_by(Group) %>% mutate(new_val = scale_helper(Value, 100))`? I don't see any neccessarity to use `purrr` here...

Comment: I'd choose `purrr`, if you are handling multiple data.frames stored in a list. For handling a single data.frame, `dplyr` should be sufficient.

Comment: @NatashaR, you are asking whether a for loop is better, but it's not clear to me how to measure that without knowing why you don't want to use one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop for is not good way, but I don't understand why you want to use purr. I think, this is good version:

```
df %>% group_by(Group) %>% mutate(Value = scale_helper(Value, 100)) %>% as.data.frame()
```

Or you can use data.table. Something like this:

```
as.data.table(df)[, lapply(.SD, scale_helper, 100), keyby = Group]
```